# Обрабатывание ошибки ввода целого числа пользователем

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код для ввода числа

```
number = str(input('print even number '))
if int(number) in lst():
    return True
```

список состоит из чисел,
нужно сделать обработку ошибки если

```
type(number) != int
```

но при таком условии все равно выдает ошибку ввода.
Как решить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обернуть в `try`/`except` для обработки исключения:

```
number = input('print even number ')

try:
    if int(number) in lst():
        return True

except ValueError:
    print("Введено неправильное число")
```